# How to validate this string not to contain any special characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a dynamic string like this which may look like:

```
"69.43.202.97"                 OR               "ngs.pradhi.com"
```

I want to validate these string contains only numbers, english alphabets and "." . I want to validate this in front end using java script. I thought of using regular expression like this:

```
function validatePath() {
    var path = document.getElementById('server_path').value;
    path.match([a-z][0-9])  //or something like this
}
```

If the path is invalid despite of displaying the alert box I just want to show the error below the text field as soon as the user fills the server path. How can I do that?

My full javascript function looks like this:

```
function validatePath() {
    var path = document.getElementById('server_path').value;
    if (path.search(":") == -1){
        alert("Invalid server path");
    }
    else{
        var host_name = path.split(":")[0]
        if host_name.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$")) {}

    }
```

}

Comment: `/[a-zA-Z0-9]/` is the proper notation here.

Comment: Do you want `host_name` to be matched? Or do you want `path` to be matched with the `:`?

Comment: I want host_name to be matched.

Comment: @user2032220: Just curious, what was wrong with my answer to "un-accept" it ???

Comment: Nothing wrong, but @dshu610 gave the answer before you did. I will +1 your answer. Thanks

Comment: @user2032220: It's not about the reps. I just found it strange to accept my answer and then "un-accept" it, so I thought I'd ask to satisfy my curiosity :) I am rarely the quickest to answer, since I try to address the problem thoroughly, provide links to related docs and prepare a short demo to illustrate my proposed solution (all of which requires time), but in the end it is a matter of style I guess . Thx for the upvote anyway ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `path.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$")`

EDIT: 
    `var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$");
    if(regex.test(host_name)){}`

Comment: See my updated question. How would I include this in my above function.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$/.test(path)` which will return true or false

Answer (score 1):

To be different, replace method:

```
if(path.replace(/^[a-z\d.]*$/i,"")=="")
```

Comment: Note that underscore (_) counts as a word character, so not what the OP wants. Better to use `/[^a-z\d\.]/i` in this case.

Comment: Updated answer, to be different

Answer (score 1):

You can do the check (including port presence) with a regex like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+:[0-9]+$
```

(Note the `+` instead of `*` to account for empty path or port (they are not allowed).)

If you are using HTML5, consider the newly introduced "pattern" and "required" attributes, which can posdibly save you some JS code.

See this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/MZN6m/)** for an illustration of both technics.

Some links you might find useful:

- **[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)**
- **[The HTML5 "pattern" attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute)**
- **[The HTML5 "required" attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute)**